# NGS Lurbe Drivers

Tags: drivers, webcam

Where can i get drivers for NGS Lurbe webcam drivers for XP

Comment: I suggest you to contact the NGS Lurbe support via email.

Comment: There is no link to their support site nor is there any email address to contact their support team. if you have any of this please help

Comment: This company is kinda weired, regarding to http://www.ip-adress.com/whois/ngslurbe.com the server is located near Kassel, Germany. This is a bit strange, because every commercial site in Germany must have a imprint.